# Why is dapper returning every number column as Int64?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  [Person].[Id] AS [Person_Id],
  [Person].[Name] AS [Person_Name],
  [Address].[Id] AS [Address_Id],
  [Address].[Number] AS [Address_Number],
  [Address].[Street] AS [Address_Street],        
FROM [Person]
LEFT JOIN [Address] ON [Person].[addressId] = [Address].[Id]
```

Which is used to query a `SQLite` in-memory DB as:

```
var rows = _database.Query(query);
```

However when I try to read the values as `Int32` I get `InvalidCastException`.

```
foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in rows)
{
    var someId = (int)row["Person_Id"];
    var someNumber = (int)row["Address_Number"];
}
```

The reason why I am using `dapper` like so is that as a side project I am building some features on top of `dapper` to map the values to a `POCO` (I am aware of the similar projects e.g. `rainbow`, `dapper.extensions` etc).

So something along the lines of:

```
var rowVal = row[fieldName];
propInfo.SetValue(obj, rowVal, null);
```

Again, ignore the performance cost associated with the reflection call.

In the example above the property type of the `POCO` is `int32` and because of this problem I cannot assign the value to the `obj`.

Any help or ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It isn't dapper doing this. However, some RDBMS *do this internally* (meaning: expose integers as Int64). I want to blame mysql, but I can't remember which is the one that does this. Basically, if you use `Query<Foo>` *with recent builds*, it should work around it automatically. I would hope that it would work when using the `dynamic` API too. However, if you use the raw unbox API (like you are), then you **need** to unbox to the type of the actual data - that's an inbuilt limitation of how unboxing in C# works.

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for the comment, I am using `SQLite` and an old version of `Dapper`, I will switch to the latest and report back.

Comment: note: if you keep using the `IDictionary<string,object>` API, I would expect it to keep failing - at that point you're just unboxing, and unboxing needs to be done to the right type (ish, there are exceptions)

Comment: true, totally forgot about the perf side of the box-unbox aswell! How would you recommend I get to the row?

Comment: by defining a type called `Person` (or whatever) any using `Query<Person>(sql, args)`

Comment: I cannot use the generic type as my Pocos are nested e.g. `Person` has an `Address` property, I am aware of the `MultiMapping` feature of  Dapper but I need to do this at runtime. hence the format of the `SQL` query above. I parse the `Poco` and generate the query based on the property names and then use `JOIN` to relate them together then run that against the DB and use `FastMember` to patch the object that's why I need to access each column. I hope it's more clear what I am trying to achieve. Does `dapper` support returning an `IDataReader`? are there any examples?

Comment: yes, you can use recent versions to get the raw data-reader. You could always create a new type that matches your query and use that as an intermediate POCO. Or just unbox to long, if that is what sqlite is returning - `=(int)(long)row["whatever"]`

Comment: Ok great, I will use the latest version to work with the datareader, ideally I want a solution that runs on any DBMS, currently playing with SQLite but the target is all the major DBMSs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Dapper, it's SQLite. See [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (assuming you're actually using v3):

> The INTEGER storage class, for example, includes 6 different integer datatypes of different lengths. This makes a difference on disk. B*ut as soon as INTEGER values are read off of disk and into memory for processing, they are converted to the most general datatype (8-byte signed integer)*. And so for the most part, "storage class" is indistinguishable from "datatype" and the two terms can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Yes I am using an in-memory `SQLite` database. But according to the extract above since it is already in memory, it should be read as `int32` (32bit signed integer) no?

Comment: The extract says that the datatype will be 8 bytes, ie Int64.